# Polymorphic, get user liked activities

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, laravel-query-builder

I have a polymorphic one-to-many realtionship defined between Activity and Like.
A User can like the activity but
how can I get all activities liked by a user?

```
class Activity extends Model
{   
    public function likes(){
        return $this->morphMany('App\Like', 'likeable');
    }

    public function like($user = 0){
        $this->likes()->updateOrCreate([
            'user_id' => $user ? $user->id : Auth::id(),
        ], [
            'liked' => true
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
class Like extends Model
{
    public function likeable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function likes(){
        // Get all liked activities by a user.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

In `User` model:

```
public function likes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
}
```

And retrieving likes would be; `$user->likes->where('liked', true);`

My first answer was wrong.

Or you can use package for likes:
https://github.com/overtrue/laravel-like

Comment: $user->likes throwing ERROR:  LogicException with message 'App/User::likes must return a relationship instance.'

Comment: This is returning the like itself, but how can I get the belonging activity to that like?

Comment: Retrieving `Activity` model: `$user->likes->where('liked', true)->where('likeable_id', $activity_id)->likeable;`

Comment: I wrote an answer, maybe you can check that too for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with:

```
    public function likedActivities(){
        $collection = collect();
        foreach ($this->likes as $like) {
            $collection = $collection->add($like->likeable);
        }
        return $collection;
    }
```

This returns all Activities liked by a user.
Is there maybe a more elegant way to do so?